# Attach SVN to existing repo file structure

Tags: svn, repository

I have a few SVN repositories that have been unfortunately been given to me as zip files of the raw repo structure (db, locks, hooks, conf folders, etc), rather than a dump file.

What is the best way to "reattach" SVN to the repo structure so that it can be used in place?

Unfortunately I have no access to the original repo so I cannot go back and do a dump.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular "attachment" between an installed SVN and its repositories, and the repository structure of SVN has not changed in a while although I'm not sure about minor incompatibilites between different systems.

I'd try just unzipping the directories in a place accesible to your SVN configuration as if they were natively created repositories. Or unzipping them somewhere and trying to use svndump locally to create a dump if you feel more comfortable doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly try to create a machine (or a virtual machine) with the same OS and SVN version as the original, so that the database formats are identical.  Then do an [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.html) to extract the repository in a portable way, and then you can do `svnadmin load` into your desired destination system.  I've been a similar situation before and this method has worked well.